# How to validate written css code is valid css or not?

Tags: jquery, css, css3pie

I'm working on a project where the user can write custom CSS which will be applied to his website.
My concern is how can I validate that CSS code, whether it is right or not?
I want to implement a CSS editor like WordPress custom CSS editor.
Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: you can try use validator by w3 [validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri)

Comment: does w3 validator provides api to validate css code?

Comment: [link](https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html)